# Need help populating Google Sheets from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, hubspot

thanks in advance for any help.

I'm trying to get data from my Hubspot account into a Google Sheet, using their Analytics API (https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/analytics/get-analytics-data-breakdowns)

I've written the following script in Google App Script:

```js
var url = API_URL + "/analytics/v2/reports/totals/summarize/daily?&start=20181201&end=20181219";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
var json = response.getContentText();
var dataALL = JSON.parse(json);
var dataSet = dataALL;

Logger.log(dataALL);

var rows = [],
    data;

for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet[i];
  rows.push(data.visits, data.leads);
}

Logger.log(rows)

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2);

dataRange.setValues([rows])
```

But when I try `Logger.log(rows)` it comes out empty. When I try `Logger.log(dataSet.length)` it returns 0.0

So I gather I'm making a mistake getting the JSON data into the array. I've done tones of research, but could not find a solution that works for my specific case.

The JSON I'm trying to write into the spreadsheet has the following format:

```
 {2018-12-03   =   [  
      {  
         contactsPerPageview=0.15384615384615385,
         rawViews=143,
         subscribers=1,
         contactToCustomerRate=0.045454545454545456,
         privacyConsentDeclines=11,
         customersPerPageview=0.006993006993006993,
         sessionToContactRate=0.2037037037037037,
         pageviewsPerSession=1.3240740740740742,
         opportunities=3,
         visits=108,
         visitors=98,
         submissionsPerPageview=0.027972027972027972,
         submissions=4,
         leads=17,
         privacyConsentApproves=9,
         customers=1,
         contacts=22,
         newVisitorSessionRate=0.9074074074074074
      }
   ],

2018-12-14   =   [  
      {  
         contactsPerPageview=0.06722689075630252,
         rawViews=238,
         subscribers=4,
         privacyConsentDeclines=14,
         sessionToContactRate=0.08290155440414508,
         pageviewsPerSession=1.233160621761658,
         opportunities=6,
         visits=193,
         visitors=182,
         submissionsPerPageview=0.029411764705882353,
         submissions=7,
         leads=6,
         privacyConsentApproves=12,
         contacts=16,
         newVisitorSessionRate=0.9430051813471503
      }]}
```

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Thanks again,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dataSet` is an object, it does not have a `.length` property, and your `for` loop will check if `i` is smaller than `Undefined`, which results in false. This means the for loop never runs.

I think what you're trying to achieve is closer to the following:

```
  var dataSet = Object.keys(dataALL);

  Logger.log(dataALL);

  var rows = [], data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {

      data = dataALL[dataSet[i]];
      rows.push(data[0].visits, data[0].leads);
  }

  Logger.log(rows)
```

Note that since each key in your object contains an array, I also added `[0]` to both `data.visits` and `data.leads`, resulting in `rows.push(data[0].visits, data[0].leads);`.